# PostgreSQL Order the records bases on number of days between the date range

Tags: spring, postgresql, sorting, psql

I want to fetch the records from the database based on number of days between the 2 columns, the data type in the database column is ***timestamp without time zone***  *(sample format 2023-04-05 04:00:00)* . we are using `org.springframewrk.data.domain.Sort` for sorting. It works as expected for 1 date column but I am unable to set for the date range .

For example if I have 2023-04-05 04:00:00 and 2023-04-08 04:00:00 then the result should be 3 . Since number of days between the two date range is 3

*Before sorting*

```
opendate               closedate            number of days
2023-04-05 04:00:00   2023-04-06 04:00:00       1
2023-04-05 04:00:00   2023-04-05 04:00:00       0
2023-04-05 04:00:00   2023-04-07 04:00:00       2
2023-04-05 04:00:00   2023-04-05 04:00:00       0
2023-04-05 04:00:00   2023-04-08 04:00:00       3
```

*After sorting*

```
opendate               closedate            number of days
2023-04-05 04:00:00   2023-04-05 04:00:00       0
2023-04-05 04:00:00   2023-04-05 04:00:00       0
2023-04-05 04:00:00   2023-04-06 04:00:00       1
2023-04-05 04:00:00   2023-04-07 04:00:00       2
2023-04-05 04:00:00   2023-04-08 04:00:00       3
```

I want to set the below ordering ie

```
 select * from table order by (date(closedDate)-date(openDate)) desc ;
```

The above query gives the expected result but I want to achieve the same using the sort function ie

I am using

```
    import org.springframewrk.data.domain.*;

    Sort sort=Sort.by(openDate).descending();
  Pageable paging=PageRequest.of(1,10,sort);
```

I want something like

```
 Sort sort=Sort.by(closedDate-openDate).descending();
```

Is it possible to do this using the Sort function

Comment: To your question text add: 1) What are the actual types for `datecolumnm1` and `datecolumn2`, `date` or `timestamp(tz)`? 2) If `date` then `datecolumn1-datecolumn2` will yield an `integer`. If `timestamp(tz)` then it will yield an `interval`. 3) Provide (**as text**) a sample of the input data and a sample of the expected output.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver have updated the format in the question. Sample format is (2023/04/05)

Comment: That is not what I asked. What we need to know is what is the data type for the columns involved? This `2023/04/05` means nothing as that is not how the data is stored. Also you have not provided input data and what you expect as output.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver In the data base the column date type is time stamp without time zone

Comment: 1) As I said before when you subtract two timestamps you get an interval: `select '2023-11-11 7:57'::timestamp -'2023-11-10 10:15'::timestamp; 21:42:00` 2) For the last time provide a set of example input data and sample output data showing how you want the sort to be done.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I have updated the sample input and output in my question

Comment: This `order by (date(closedDate)-date(openDate))` and this `Sort.by(closedDate-openDate).descending()` are not the same thing. As mentioned previously the first is subtracting dates which will yield an `integer`, the second is subtracting timestamps which will yield an `interval`. Naming something a date does not make it one, you will need to cast `closedDate` and `openDate` to dates in Spring.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver when I run select * from table order by (date(closedDate)-date(openDate)) desc ; I get the expected result. But I want to achieve the same functionality using the sort function

Comment: As I mentioned in my previous comment you need to replicate that in the Spring code by casting the values to dates. I don't use Spring so that is something you will need to look up or someone else will need to provide the answer.